# Orchestrate Dataflow job using Dataflowpythonoperator

Tags: airflow, dataflow, google-cloud-composer

Need some advise with running  Dataflow job on airflow .I can run  beam job locally and on dataflow runner for wordcount example using Python sdk. But could not orchestrate the job via airflow  using DataflowPythonOperator (not sure if it is deprecated) . I had no issues using Dataflowjavaoperator orchestrating jar files.

example_composer_..._operator = DataFlowPythonOperator(

```
    gcp_conn_id='gcp_default',
    task_id='composer_dataflow_python_...',
    py_file='gs://dataflow.../WordCountPython.py',
    job_name='Airflow ... Job ',
    py_options=None,
    dataflow_default_options=None,
    options=None,
```

Any advise on how I should make approach this issue and if I am doing anything wrong. Should I use Python operator to call the wordcountpython.py file

Cheers

Comment: Did you get any errors? And what's the outcome you got from running that?

Answer (score 2):

The `Dataflowjavaoperator` is deprecated you should use `DataflowCreateJavaJobOperator`.

You can import the operator from providers. Usage example:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowCreateJavaJobOperator
task = DataflowCreateJavaJobOperator(
    gcp_conn_id="gcp_default",
    task_id="normalize-cal",
    jar="{{var.value.gcp_dataflow_base}}pipeline-ingress-cal-normalize-1.0.jar",
    options={
        "autoscalingAlgorithm": "BASIC",
        "maxNumWorkers": "50",
        "start": "{{ds}}",
        "partitionType": "DAY",
    },
    dag=dag,
)
```

If you want to use the python version then you should use `DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator`. Usage example:

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator

start_python_job = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
    task_id="start-python-job",
    py_file=GCS_PYTHON,
    py_options=[],
    job_name='{{task.task_id}}',
    options={
        'output': GCS_OUTPUT,
    },
    py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.21.0'],
    py_interpreter='python3',
    py_system_site_packages=False,
    location='europe-west3',
)
```

If you are running Airflow < 2.0.0 you can get these operators by installing [Google backport provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/) by:

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-google
```

If you are running Airflow >= 2.0.0 you can get these operators by installing [Google provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-google
```

Comment: Hi Elad  I could run the job by using Python Operator and saving the required arguments in config.py file .Made a callable function call in Dag Thanks